# Extracting radio signal strength from multiband TIFF file

Tags: propagation, rf-power

I have N number of TIFF files corresponding to each radio stations in my data, and I am trying to measure the approximate signal strengths from each of these stations at K geographic locations(say for example, municipalities)
My aim is to build a N x K database. But the problem is that my TIFF files are multiband - 3RGB + 1 Alpha, i.e., for each station-municipality combination, I have four measures of average signal strength: Avg_R, Avg_G, Avg_B and Avg_Alpha.
So, I was wondering what I should do if I wanted to create a single measure of signal strength for each of these station-municipality combinations with minimal loss in information (i.e., I would really like to use the information we have from all the four bands, assuming of course that would be the correct way to go).

I used [Cloud RF](https://cloudrf.com/) to generate the output. The geocoded TIFF files give me the extent of signal spread, and I'm using a shapefile(at the municipality-level) to calculate the average signal strength at my locations of interest. I'm using QGIS, and I already have the zonal statistics, i.e., the average signal strengths for the 4 bands (3RGBs + Alpha; Avg_R, Avg_G, Avg_B and Avg_Alpha) corresponding to each geographic location. My question was more theoretical: if I wanted to get a single value of signal strength for each locations, what would be ideal way (theoretically) to combine the four averages?

Thank you.

Comment: I've never heard of TIFF image files being used to store radio signals or strength (unless you count graphical representations of waveform or waterfall, which are _not at all_ standardized in color). Can you please provide more detail on format you have the data in, or the software or supplier that produced it? We can't tell you how to process the data if we don't know what the format is.

Comment: @KevinReidAG6YO I used [Cloud RF](https://cloudrf.com/) to generate the output. The geocoded TIFF files give me the extent of signal spread, and I'm using a shapefile(at the municipality-level) to calculate the average signal strength at my locations of interest.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Please [edit] your question to include that information — comments are intended to be disposable.

Comment: Welcome Parijat! This does feel on-topic enough here, but I do wonder if you might get more answers on https://gis.stackexchange.com/ too? (If you'd like I believe a mod could migrate it.) On either site, it might help to fill in your answer more with what tools you would are able to use — only GUI tools like QGIS or other? or programming GDAL from Python?

Comment: @natevw-AF7TB I'm using QGIS, and I already have the zonal statistics, i.e., the average signal strengths for the 4 bands (3RGBs + Alpha; Avg_R, Avg_G, Avg_B and Avg_Alpha) corresponding to each geographic location. My question was more theoretical: if I wanted to get a single value of signal strength for each locations, what would be ideal way (theoretically) to combine the four averages.

Comment: Still struggling to understand ... It sounds like you are trying to average the signal strengths from 4 different bands, but that doesn't make any sense.  Your receiver will only be tuned to one of the 4 bands at any given time.  Am I missing something?